# Read a SNS message at AWS Lambda Function written in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda function at AWS written in c#. This lambda function would read an incoming SNS message. Below is my lambda code.

```
public void FunctionHandler(Amazon.Lambda.SNSEvents.SNSEvent.SNSMessage message, ILambdaContext context)
        {                  
            if (message.Message == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("message is null");
            }
            else if (message.Message == string.Empty)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("message is empty");
            }
            else
            {
              Console.WriteLine(message.Message);
            }
       }
    }
```

I have subscribed this lambda function to a SNS Topic. The lambda function is triggered when I publish the SNS message, but the message is always shown null. i.e the output I am getting is :

```
message is null
```

Can anyone help me in reading the SNS message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Amazon.Lambda.SNSEvents](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.SNSEvents):

```
public class Function
{
    public string Handler(SNSEvent snsEvent)
    {
        foreach (var record in snsEvent.Records)
        {
            var snsRecord = record.Sns;
            Console.WriteLine($"[{record.EventSource} {snsRecord.Timestamp}] Message = {snsRecord.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

So, it seems that `SNSEvent` contacts an array of `Records`, that contain `Message`.

Start by changing your debug to print `message` instead of `message.Message` and take it from there.